# How to get the Type of c++0x lambda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I want get the type of lambda as the template argument. How to do this?

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(T t){ t(); }
};

int main()
{   
    Foo< type?? > foo([](){ cout<<"construct OK"; });

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible to deduce the type of a lambda-expression when it is the argument to a function template function parameter whose type is deduced.

Lambda expressions however are explicitly forbidden to appear inside an unevaluated operand --- this includes `decltype`. It was found that this includes several yet unhandled special cases and it was found that there is no real utility to allow lambda expressions inside `decltype` and friends. Recall that every lambda expression creates a new unique type.

You can instead use `std::function<void()>`, which is able to store any function object that can be called without arguments and yields `void` as return type.

```
Foo< std::function<void()> > foo([](){ cout<<"construct OK"; });
```

Of course, as I said above, function templates can deduce their argument type, so you can also make the constructor a template

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Foo(T t){ t(); }
};

Foo foo([](){ cout<<"construct OK"; });
```

But I take it that this is not really useful in your case, since you presumably want to do something with `T` inside your class definition. Like, storing the object as a non-static data member. With `std::function`, that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is still the old-fashioned way of using functions to deduce types:

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(T t){ t(); }
};

template <typename T>
Foo<T> make_foo(T const& t)
{
    return Foo<T>(t);
}

... make_foo([](){ cout<<"construct OK"; });
```

but I guess compilers that support lambdas usually support `decltype` and `auto` as well, therefore Matteo's answer is probably better.